# How to create formula to calculate sum depend on group condition in crystal report

Tags: winforms, crystal-reports

I have crystal report that group by ticket type, journey type and process.

In group process I have type:

1. ticket sales
2. ticket cancel

Total for each group I can do it by insert summary.
But then, at the last grand total (net sales) I want only sum of ticket sales, excluded ticket cancel..so how to do that..?

my formula is:

```
If ({Command.process})= "0") Then
(
    Sum ({Command.quantity}, {Command.process})
)
```

0 = ticket sales
2 = ticket cancel

Comment: according to me you should get canceled tickets in a separate field and just subtract it with the total sum of qty

Comment: ok..can you explain separate field? i bind crystal report with query.so my query has to select ticket sales and ticket cancel together as crystal report dont support 2 dataset.

Comment: what is the problem with formula?

Answer (score 0):

Use running total fields:

1. create running total fields
2. give it a name
3. field to summarize: anyone, may be an id
4. type of summary: count
5. evaluate for each record
6. reset : use a formula  {Command.process})= "0"

This will count all the tickets of process "sales". The trick is the step 6 that says to count only when that is the process.